# elementary database design

Tags: sql, database

I'm doing a little side-project in php and SQL to get my feet wet with databases. I don't have any formal training in databases, I just have a working knowledge of SQL.

I plan to track Objects in an object table, and Properties in a property table. Suppose there are 100 properties, but that will probably expand in the future. Both of these tables would only need two columns.

Naively, I would record which objects have which properties in a table whose columns are the Property IDS and rows are the Object ids. The entries would simply be boolean "true/false/null" depending on if the object is known to have or lack the property. Whenever a new object is added, one row with its 100 columns would need to be added. When a new property is added, one column with a row for each object must be added.

However, I have read before that if you're worrying about how many columns there are, you have a design problem. An alternate table was suggested to me by a friend. It would have three columns, and an entry would just consist of the Object ID, Property ID and the corresponding boolean. In this scheme, adding a new object would necessitate adding 100 new rows to this table.

Can someone clarify which of the two designs is better and why? Is having a lot of columns more problematic than having a lot of rows for some reason?

I would be entirely unsurprised if this were a duplicate question, and I appreciate your help in pointing out the right question for me, in that case. Thanks!

Comment: 100 columns? I can't possibly see why you would need this many columns. Working knowledge of SQL doesn't really help with database design. Look into [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and [relational models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model)

Comment: @njk I'm hoping not to use that many, I'm just saying from a beginner's point of view, an $n\times m$ grid is the easiest way to envision recording the status of $m$ properties on $n$ objects. I realize it is probably better stored in a different manner.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a `Many-to-Many` relationship because an object can have many properties and at the same time property belongs many objects. (*Right? I hope so*) My suggested database schema would be

Table Object

- ObjectID (PK)
- ObjectName (Unique)

Table Property

- PropertyID (PK)
- PropertyName (Unique)

Table Object_Property (this is a *mapping* table)

- ObjectID (FK)
- PropertyID (FK)

Example Records and Queries,

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*click here*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f26e2/9)

Comment: Yes, many-to-many. Thanks also for including info on how the keys would be chosen! This is very helpful...

Comment: Just a quick question: How would the Object_Property table you are proposing can hold the True/False/Null records for each pair involved? When given an ObjectID, I'm going to have a query return the status of all Properties, many of which may be unknown. Would it be a third column in that table? If so, it sounds like you are vouching for the second method I mentioned in the OP.

Comment: Wjy would you want to add anothrr column for the status? You can easily check the status through query, have you seen the demo on the fiddle? See the last query on it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I had not tried out the link yet. It's a neat little tool :) From what I can read, it looks like for each object you can indicate it *has* a property, or else you can leave it blank. But really, I think I need to maintain all three possible states: *is-a*, *is-not-a* and *unknown*. As information was gathered, the unknowns would gradually be converted to *is-a* or *is-not-a*. It's possible that there are some unknowns that nobody knows how to fill in.

Comment: Can you answer my "Is having lots of columns bad compared to lots of rows?" question? From what I read, it sounds like nobody expects to have many columns, but thousands of rows would be just fine. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

To get started I would suggest that you create as many tables as you have different types of objects and that you go ahead and put the specific properties of each distinct object within the table as a column.  If you are building a complex relational database, some of these properties will be pulled out into other tables, but if it is simple, then it should not be a problem.

It is hard to understand what you are doing when you only describe the domain in terms of objects and properties - essentially, with your db, you are creating a logical view of the domain you are representing.

For instance in a simple Orders db, you might have tables for customers, products and orders.  The properties of the customer - like name, address & phone might be columns in your customer table.  However, you may find it easier to break addresses out into a separate table because you could have a customer who uses the same address as their billing address and their shipping address.

I find it easier to discuss design in more concrete terms.  I would worry about perfecting or optimizing your database after you have the basics down and can create a functioning system.

Check out [The Pragmatic Programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161622X) on Amazon.

Comment: Sorry... since I have no plans to budget time beyond this project for SQL, it's infeasible for me to get too deep into it. I also can't envision how to take the batch of tables for each object and then query them to see which objects have a certain property. (maybe it's possible but I definitely don't know how to do it :) ) It seems like I would want to relate them in a single table and then query it.